# URL length problems on iFrame

Tags: url, iframe, get, jboss6.x

Hello everyone I'm having some problems when a calling an iframe that has an specific URL length: The complete URL is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/autorizaciones/pages/administracion/autorizaciones/solicitarAutorizacion.jsf?nkttxms=6175141345567386080&nosjxms =%7B%22formActionURL%22%3A%22crearCotizacion.do%22%2C%22renderSection%22%3A%5B%22%27div_pagina%27%22%2C%22%27mensajes%27%22%5D%2C%22formName%22%3A%22cotizarRecotizarReservarForm%22%2C%22loadMenu%22%3Afalse%2C%22scriptParameters%22%3A%7B%22evalScripts%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22viewParameters%22%3A%7B%22autorizaciones%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22codigoSistema%5C%22%3A%5C%22SISPE%5C%22%2C%5C%22descripcion%5C%22%3A%5C%22Solicito+autorizacion+descuento+variable+del+5.0%25+para+la%28s%29+clasificacion%28es%29%3A+2226-PAVOS+CONGELADOS+%5C%22%2C%5C%22areaTrabajo%5C%22%3A%5C%22MULTICENTRO%5C%22%2C%5C%22tituloAutorizacion%5C%22%3A%5C%22AUTORIZACION+DESCUENTO+VARIABLE+GERENTE+COMERCIAL+5.0%5C%22%2C%5C%22filtroTipoAutorizacion%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%227%5C%22%3A%5B%7B%5C%22codigoComponente%5C%22%3A23%2C%5C%22valorComponente%5C%22%3A%5C%225.0%5C%22%2C%5C%22soloLectura%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%7D%2C%5C%22filtroUsuariosAutorizadores%5C%22%3A%5B%5C%22FRM1458%5C%22%5D%2C%5C%22dataKeys%5C%22%3A%5B%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22AREA+TRABAJO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22101%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22NUMERO+PEDIDO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22TOTAL+PEDIDO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22925.6999999999999%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22VALOR+APLICAR+DESCUENTO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22253.4%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22NUMERO+DOCUMENTO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%221104627169%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22NOMBRE+CONTACTO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22OCHOA+VASQUEZ+PABLO+IVAN%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%2C%5C%22secuencial%5C%22%3A1%7D%2C%7B%5C%22codigoSistema%5C%22%3A%5C%22SISPE%5C%22%2C%5C%22descripcion%5C%22%3A%5C%22Solicito+autorizacion+descuento+variable+del+5.0%25+para+la%28s%29+clasificacion%28es%29%3A+1602-CANASTAS+%5C%22%2C%5C%22areaTrabajo%5C%22%3A%5C%22MULTICENTRO%5C%22%2C%5C%22tituloAutorizacion%5C%22%3A%5C%22AUTORIZACION+DESCUENTO+VARIABLE+GERENTE+COMERCIAL+5.0%5C%22%2C%5C%22filtroTipoAutorizacion%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%227%5C%22%3A%5B%7B%5C%22codigoComponente%5C%22%3A23%2C%5C%22valorComponente%5C%22%3A%5C%225.0%5C%22%2C%5C%22soloLectura%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%7D%2C%5C%22filtroUsuariosAutorizadores%5C%22%3A%5B%5C%22KFLOW100%5C%22%5D%2C%5C%22dataKeys%5C%22%3A%5B%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22AREA+TRABAJO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22101%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22NUMERO+PEDIDO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22TOTAL+PEDIDO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22925.6999999999999%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22VALOR+APLICAR+DESCUENTO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22600.3%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22NUMERO+DOCUMENTO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%221104627169%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22NOMBRE+CONTACTO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22OCHOA+VASQUEZ+PABLO+IVAN%5C%22%2C%5C%22hasAction%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22isVisibleInManageTaskDescription%5C%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%2C%5C%22secuencial%5C%22%3A2%7D%5D%22%2C%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22%23F4F5EB%22%2
```

I know that it has a lot of data on it's query string, and that I **should** use **POST** when transferring large quantities of data. However, that's the way the system creates them... that was already done before I found the problem. 
The main problem is that a lot of modules have dependencies on this, and changing it would make it impossible to accomplish deadlines (next week).

Now we use that URL in the following iframe:

```
<iframe name="Contactos" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" class="tabla_informacion" src="urlAbove" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

However when the frame appears it just shows a blank screen, no callbacks at all are triggered on the server....

Now if we reduce the url length it works correctly. At first glance I thought it was a problem related to header lengths on **jBOSS AS 6** (by default 8KB), so I changed it on the server.conf file and increased it to 64KB. No luck at all...

But then when I used **Firefox's Poster plugin** to create a GET request with the whole URL, it worked correctly and server breakpoints where triggered, meaning that it's not a server's problem, at least at the current URL length....

Maybe is a browser limitation? (We are using Internet Explorer...) is it a know problem? Or maybe there is something that I'm missing when calling iFrames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possibly a browser limit.  The fact that the page loads (or at least the request gets to the server) in Firefox is a good hint.

Your URL is 4,097 characters, and the [limit in IE is 2,083](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).